# Sass does not compile mixins and variables into css

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I have added font and tried to make mixin (also tried as varible, result is the same) to use it.

All sass files are connected through "style.sass"

```
@import '_interface'
@import '_fonts'
```

file "_fonts.sass", where I added font and made mixin

```
@font-face
    font-family: 'Museo Sans Light'
    src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot')
    src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.ttf') 
    format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@mixin reg
    font-family: 'Museo Sans Light'
    font-weight: 300
```

Then I tried to use it into "_interface.sass" for body tag:

```
body
    box-sizing: border-box
    color: $text-color
    +reg
```

In the result I caught sass exception "no mixin named reg"

I will very grateful, If someone help!
Thank You.

Comment: You don't put the underscore in the '@import' references, so should just be @import 'interface'

Comment: hm, I tried to import file in both options. However, result did not changed

Comment: Try switching the order of your files. If `reg` is defined in `_fonts`, it needs to be imported before it is used in `_interface`.

Comment: @ajm Yes, that`s it. I am really grateful to You. Thanks!)

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer so more people can find it and then you can mark it correct/accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS files are processed and loaded in an order-dependent way, so the file in which a `mixin` (or variable or function, etc.) is declared must be `import`ed before that `mixin` is used in other files.

In your example, your `mixin` `reg` is declared in `_fonts` and used in `_interface`. For SASS to recognize and load `reg`, `_fonts` must be `import`ed. After `_fonts` is `import`ed, all subsequently loaded files, like `_interface`, will have access to `reg`.

A common pattern of working with shared SASS mixins, variables, or functions, is to create and store them in a single place (e.g. a file named `_mixins`, `_vars`, `_functions`) which you then `import` in your main `SASS` stylesheet before individual stylesheet modules. That way, you know that everything you need is already declared and available.

That might look something like this:

```
@import "_vars"; // Everything below knows about contents of _vars
@import "_mixins";  // Everything below knows about contents of _mixins

// These files can use everything above!
@import "_fileThatUsesSharedVariables";
@import "_fileThatUsesMixins";
@import "_fileThatUsesMixinsAndVariables"; // This last file can use everything above it!
```